# Why does my pyinstaller created executable require admin privileges?

Tags: pyqt4, pygame, pyinstaller

I've written a Python program which I distribute using pyinstaller. I've been using the `onefile` option so far to create a standalone executable. That's been great up until now, but  as the application has grown the startup time is getting a bit long. I'd also like users to install the application properly to make upgrading simpler.

I've been trying to create a single directory version of the app using pyinstaller's `onedir` option. However, the resulting .exe file that is created requires admin privileges to run, which the `onefile` version did not. The program itself doesn't need any such privileges so I assume this is something that pyinstaller is doing. How do I create an application that doesn't require admin privileges?

Additional info:

- Python 2.6, pyinstaller v1.4
- Application uses PyQt4 and pygame modules.
- Trying to create executable for Windows 7.
- Using -w pyinstaller option to create a windowless executable.

Comment: It could just as easily be something that Windows is doing. It has some degree of installer auto-detection and it could be marking your executable as such. Ideally, a program should specify the access level that it requires in its manifest. Not sure if Pyinstaller lets you do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have recently run into this issue, and my experience in solving it was thus:

PyInstaller with `--onefile` option creates a manifest file in the 'executable'. This manifest file on Windows tells the OS a few things about the application it is bundled with. One of the  things it specifies, is the application name/manifest file. The format of the manifest filename is `appname.exe.manifest`. If your program is frozen with PyInstaller, the executable name that it stores in the manifest *will be the name given to the completed EXE* under the `/dist` folder of PyInstaller. **IF you rename the EXE, the manifest file packed with it is no longer matching!** Therefore, create a manifest file with the same name as the final EXE filename and run PyInstaller with the `--manifest` option, OR don't rename the EXE that PyInstaller creates.

When you package the PyInstaller project with the custom `--manifest`, the renamed program no longer requests administrator elevation.

Answer (score 17):

admin privileges could be asked in few cases:

A. if the executable name contains relevant keywords (like `setup`, `install`, `update` or `patch`)

B. the application requests it in it's manifest.

C. the .exe file name do not match the name in the manifest file.

if you create a .spec file for your application package, you can add

```
exe = EXE(
    ...
    manifest=None,
    ...
    )
```

and it won't ask for password, unless you rename it to setup or install.

Comment: The "A. if the executable name contains relevant keywords (like setup, install, update or patch)" save my life.