# App-bundle created with pyinstaller requires chmod a+x before it can run on other systems

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I've made a cross-platform application in python, with pyqt gui.

I have then successfully created an app-bundle with pyinstallers, but I have one problem.

When I use the app bundle on another computer, I have to go in and run

```
chmod a+x [myapp].app/Content/MacOS/mybinary
```

to get it to run.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you creating the app as root?

Comment: No, does that have an impact on permissions on other computers?

Comment: I believe it does, checkout the `--manifest` option, see if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969464/why-does-my-pyinstaller-created-executable-require-admin-privileges) helps

Comment: Running Makespec.py with the -m FILE option solved the problem, thank you @X.Jacobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Makespec.py with the -m FILE option as X.Jacobs suggested solved the problem.