# Pyinstaller win32 qt app not working

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have 2 virtual machines with **win32** and **win64**. I build program with PyQt5 and package it with PyInstaller(3.3.1), by using following command:

```
pyinstaller updater.py --noconsole --onefile -i icons/icon.ico
```

When I do this on **win64** machine, it works fine. Program working. But when I do the same on **win32** machine, my generated `.exe` file began require Admin privileges and even after confirm app is crashed. I checked this question: [Why does my pyinstaller created executable require admin privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969464/why-does-my-pyinstaller-created-executable-require-admin-privileges)

and rename app, but it still crashing. What can cause this ? Why on win32 defender blocks my app or maybe reason is not in defender.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(flags=QtCore.Qt.Dialog)
        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.progress_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(flags=QtCore.Qt.Widget)
        central_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.progress_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        central_widget.setLayout(central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.progress_label.setStyleSheet('color: grey')


def main():
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.setFixedSize(480, 120)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

requirements.txt:

```
PyInstaller==3.3.1
PyQt5==5.10.1
requests==2.18.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I use python 3.7, but PyIntaller not support 3.7 yet. With 3.6 works fine, but still ask Admin Rights...